# pyside read/write list of dicts

Tags: save, pyside2

I have a list of dicts that i'm trying to save to file.
the dicts are comprised of different value-types. str, int, tuples and a QFrame object..

QDataStream:ing this with a writeQStringList fails. because of the mix of stuff in the dicts? or because it's a list of dicts? it returns an empty list anyway (with correct length)
I tested with just a list of strings, this works fine.

how do I go about doing this?
should I use writeRawData? how does that work?
or do I need some custom workaround..

any ideas?
best /Sam

Comment: There is no way to "save" a `QFrame`. If you leave that out, you can just use json for the rest.

Comment: thanks! yep, that seems to be the way to go.